# Will prophecy return in the time of Mashiach?

Tags: messiah, nevua-prophecy, olam-haba-world-to-come

Will the there be prophets in the times of Moshiach?  Will everyone have some level of prophecy in the time of Mashiach?  Or is prophecy gone forever?

Comment: Why do you think it must be one of those three choices?

Comment: I can think of many other possibilities _a priori_.

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814/759

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22816/759

Comment: It doesn't have to be one of those three.  I just thought those are the three most interesting possibilities.  It could be something in between.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A posuk in Yoel ([3:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16171/jewish/Chapter-3.htm)) seems to state that everyone will have prophesy in the time of Moshiach, which answers the question will prophesy return in the time of Moshiach:

> היה אחרי כן אשפוך את רוחי על כל בשר, וניבאו בניכם ובנותיכים, זקניכם
>   חלומות יחלמון, בחוריכם חזיונות יראו
>
> And afterward I will pour out my spirit on all flesh , and your sons and daughters will be neviim, your elders will have dreams, your young men shall see visions.

Comment: It says that His ruah will be poured out upon **all** flesh and that prophecy will be found amongst the sons and daughters of our nation... it doesn't say that everyone will attain such a level however.

Answer (score 10):

The Rambam ([Hilchos Teshuva 9:2:](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911913/jewish/Chapter-Nine.htm)) writes that Moshaich will be a prophet:

> [These changes will come about] because the king who will arise from David's descendants will be a greater master of knowledge than Solomon and a **great prophet**, close to the level of Moses, our teacher.

See also [Melachim uMilchamot 12:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188357/jewish/Chapter-12.htm), where he writes that Moshaich will have "רוח הקודש".

Comment: He also states in his [Iggereth Teimon](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26834&pgnum=45) that there was a tradition in his family that prophecy would return to our nation on the precipice of the messianic era.

Comment: @Deuteronomy That answers part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of mashiach, "knowledge of God will fill the earth as waters cover the ocean." ([Chavakuk 2:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2002.htm#14))

Whether or not this equals prophecy and future-telling is up for debate.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it does imply prophecy?

Comment: Al Regel Achat, Rambam says about a navi in Hilchot Yesodei Hatorah 7:1 that.. דעתו פנויה תמיד למעלה קשורה תחת הכסא. Da'at of Hashem is a very important part of nevuah.

Comment: @EiluV'Eilu, that doesn't answer DoubleAA's question. Yediath HaShem is a necessary but not sufficient condition for prophecy.